# I need help. What height do Floating Islands spawn?

Tags: terraria

Do I just need to have a gravity potion to access them or do I not have any in my world?

Comment: Your title and body don't match, so what exactly is your question here? Punctuation also helps.

Answer (score 2):

Each world size has a floating island, although the height it's set to differs from the size of the world.

The Small map size has a maximum of 4 islands, and the approximate height for them are 250 - 600 ft. (125 - 300 tiles)

The Medium map size has a maximum of 7 islands, and the approximate height for them are 450 - 800 ft. (225 - 400 tiles)

The Large map size has a maximum of 8 islands, and the approximate height for them are 650 - 1000 ft. (325 - 500 tiles)

[Source](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Floating_Island)